# Python request to API keeps returning ZeroReturnError exception

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, raspberry-pi3

Python 2.7.3

Calling an API from a Raspberry Pi 3, the API logs show it hits the correct endpoint and returns with a 200 status code, but the python code from the Pi spits out a huge error stack.  I saw in some forums that the ZeroReturnError is always thrown meaning that there was nothing wrong, but that seems weird since I can't actually get the results of the response in an except block from the try.

My code is literally

```
import requests
response = requests.get(<URL I AM USING>, json={JSON I AM USING})
```

Not sure what to do.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "music.py", line 13, in <module>
    response = requests.get(url, json={'blah':{'blah':'*********'}})

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 49, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 457, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 606, in send
    r.content

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 724, in content
    self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 653, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 256, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 186, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 602, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 188, in recv
    data = self.connection.recv(*args, **kwargs)

OpenSSL.SSL.ZeroReturnError
```

Answer (score 0):

Some more searching brought me to think it was version issues.

Ran sudo pip install urllib3 --upgrade on the Raspberry Pi and it cleared it up.

I am getting a DependencyWarning about installing PySocks, but its working correctly now.